# no puede leer xml

Tags: python, mvc, xml, csv, odoo

Estoy haciendo un popup en el modulo de odoo que tengo pero en la vista agregue su pestaña de menu pero me marca error en una de las lineas segun esto es por cosa de los permisos ya le di los permisos pero por alguna rason sigue mandando el error

Adjunto codigo csv y xml y python

CSV:

````
```informe_carta_porte,informe_carta_porte,model_informe_carta_porte,,1,1,1,1´´´
````

Asi es como lo tengo configurado en los permisos

xml vies:

````
```<odoo>
 <menuitem id="mti_menu_informe_carta_porte" name="informe(Carta Porte)" 
 parent="stock.menu_stock_root"  sequence="1"/>
 <menuitem  action="informe_carta_porte" parent="mti_menu_informe_carta_porte" 
 id="carta_porte_menu" name="Carta"   sequence="2"/>
</odoo>```
````

Asi es como puse su menu del popup

xml wizard:

`````
```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


  <odoo>

   <record id="mti_report_view" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">mti.informe.carta.porte</field>
    <field name="model">informe_carta_porte</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form>
            <group>
                <field name="Print" widget="radio"/>
            </group>

            <footer>
                <button name="get_analysis_report" string="PDF Report"
                        type="object" class="btn-primary"/>
                <button name="get_excel_analysis_report" string="XLSX Report"
                        type="object" class="btn-primary"/>
            </footer>
        </form>
    </field>
   </record>
    <record id="mti_informe_carta_porte" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Informe de cartas porte</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
    <field name="res_model">informe_carta_porte</field>
    <field name="view_mode">form</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="mti_report_view"/>
    <field name="target">new</field>
   </record>
 </odoo>````
`````

y asi tengo el popup en el wizard no se si tambien de esto haya algun error

model python:

````
```# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from odoo import fields, api, models


class InformeCartaPorte(models.Model):

_name = ('informe_carta_porte')

consignment_note = fields.Many2one(string='Carta Porte')

Print = fields.Selection(selection=[
    ('Sin formato', 'Sin formato'),
    ('Original', 'Original'),
    ('Copia', 'Copia'),
], string='Imprimir')```
````

y asi es como hice el modelo en el archivo  de python no se a que se deba este error que manda porque no se si haya algo mal en la secuencia ya que en la termnal dice que hay algo mal en el xml que esta en views que es el menu

Adjunto imagen de la terminal:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

dice que hay un error en ir.model.access y tambien muestra una de las lineas que esta en el menu en el xml de views que podria hacer para poder corregir ese error

Comment: En el permiso tienes dos comas juntas.

Comment: estas porque se supone qu ahi va el grupo pero pero como no pertenece a ningun grupo por eso queda vacio

Comment: ya revise todo el codigo y no encuentro el error que podri ahacer ahi @Legna

Comment: El archivo de permisos si tiene los encabezados?

Comment: si id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
si a eso te refieres

Comment: o no se si este mal estructurado ya que esa opcion del menu va a brir un popup que esta en el wizard

Comment: porque esa linea que manda que esta en eol menu la ponog en el xml del wizard y no manda error pero no muestra en la interfaz la opcion

Comment: @Legna estuve volviendo a intentar y me sigue mandando el mismo error

Comment: Intenta quitar el archivo de permisos, y agrega los permisos desde la interfaz para ese modelo. O por lo menos quita la linea que parece dar el error.

Comment: hice lo mismo pero como si fuera un modulo y marca el error quito la linea y no hay error pero n isiquiera parece en el menu